# Vietnam visa requirements

Tags: vietnam, visa-free-entry

I'm traveling to Vietnam on the 1st of the month and leave on 15th.
I'm getting some conflicting information on visa exemption times.

Am I allowed to stay for the 15 days with no visa ?

As some sites say less than 15 days.

Comment: What passport do you have?

Answer (score 1):

On the Vietnam embassy website in London UK it states that it's up to 15 days, but it depends which passport you got as you didn't mention. [Vietnam embassy London](http://vietnamembassy.org.uk/index.php?action=p&ct=Notice5)